# How to split one big text file into multiple files in powershell

Tags: file, powershell, split

Hello I have one big text file like this

```
BIGFILE.TXT

COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3,COLUMN4,COLUMN5,COLUMN6,COLUMN7,COLUMN8
11/24/2013,50.67,51.22,50.67,51.12,17,0,FILE1
11/25/2013,51.34,51.91,51.09,51.87,23,0,FILE1
12/30/2013,51.76,51.82,50.86,51.15,13,0,FILE1
12/31/2013,51.15,51.33,50.45,50.76,18,0,FILE1
1/1/2014,50.92,51.58,50.84,51.1,19,0,FILE2
1/4/2014,51.39,51.46,50.95,51.21,14,0,FILE2
1/7/2014,51.08,51.2,49.84,50.05,35,0,FILE2
1/8/2014,50.14,50.94,50.01,50.78,100,0,FILE3
1/11/2014,50.63,51.41,50.52,51.3,190,0,FILE3
1/15/2014,54.03,55.74,53.69,54.93,110,0,FILE4
1/19/2014,53.67,54.19,53.55,53.82,24,0,FILE4
1/20/2014,53.83,54.26,53.47,53.53,23,0,FILE4
1/21/2014,53.8,54.55,53.7,54.1,24,0,FILE4
1/26/2014,53.26,53.93,53.23,53.65,31,0,FILE5
1/27/2014,53.78,54,53.64,53.81,110,0,FILE5
```

I'm looking for way how to split this file into multiple text files. In this case one file would be split into 5 text files. Name of each text file would be taken from column number 8. The big file is comma delimited. So the output would be:

```
FILE1.txt

COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3,COLUMN4,COLUMN5,COLUMN6,COLUMN7,COLUMN8
11/24/2013,50.67,51.22,50.67,51.12,17,0,FILE1
11/25/2013,51.34,51.91,51.09,51.87,23,0,FILE1
12/30/2013,51.76,51.82,50.86,51.15,13,0,FILE1
12/31/2013,51.15,51.33,50.45,50.76,18,0,FILE1

FILE2.TXT

COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3,COLUMN4,COLUMN5,COLUMN6,COLUMN7,COLUMN8
1/1/2014,50.92,51.58,50.84,51.1,19,0,FILE2
1/4/2014,51.39,51.46,50.95,51.21,14,0,FILE2
1/7/2014,51.08,51.2,49.84,50.05,35,0,FILE2

FILE3.TXT

COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3,COLUMN4,COLUMN5,COLUMN6,COLUMN7,COLUMN8
1/8/2014,50.14,50.94,50.01,50.78,100,0,FILE3
1/11/2014,50.63,51.41,50.52,51.3,190,0,FILE3
.
.
.
```

The big text file has several thousand of lines.
Does anybody have some idea how to do that?

Thank you for help.
J.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is exactly what I was looking for based on help from Bob McCoy

```
#  Split-File.ps1

$src = "C:\Ephemeral\bigfile.csv"
$dstDir = "C:\Ephemeral\files\"

# Delete previous output files
Remove-Item -Path "$dstDir\\*"

# Read input and create subordinate files based on column 8 content
$header = Get-Content -Path $src | select -First 1

Get-Content -Path $src | select -Skip 1 | foreach {
    $file = "$(($_ -split ",")[7]).txt"
    Write-Verbose "Wrting to $file"
    if (-not (Test-Path -Path $dstDir\$file))
    {
        Out-File -FilePath $dstDir\$file -InputObject $header -Encoding ascii
    }
    Out-File -FilePath $dstDir\$file -InputObject $_ -Encoding ascii -Append
}
```

There is just small issue with this code. It took almost 80 minutes to split my big file into 1800 small files so if anybody has some suggestion how to increase performance of this code  it would be highly appreciated. Mayby it would help that "bigfile" is sorted alphabetically by column#8.  And names for all small files are also stored in column#8.

Comment: The performance killer is that `Out-File` within `foreach` creates in your case about 250k file open - file write - file close operations. See my edited answer that buffers the output.

Comment: .@vonPryz   Thank you for your new code.It's really fast but for some reason all small files are missing first line AFTER header. And second thing is that this code is looking for row that ends with file-and-number. In fact Full names(without extension) of all small files are stored in columns #8 of a big file.  There are no numbers just text strings in column#8.
The big file is sorted Alphabetically by column#8.                But I've already found solution that exactly meet my needs so you don't have to keep trying fixing those things. Thank you for your time and help. John

Answer (score 3):

If the big file has several thousand lines, it's not that big and you could use `Import-CSV` and `Export-CSV` to handle the contents.

```
$big = Import-Csv big.csv
$big | ? { $_.column8 -eq "file1" } | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation file1.csv

# Output
cat .\file1.csv
"COLUMN1","COLUMN2","COLUMN3","COLUMN4","COLUMN5","COLUMN6","COLUMN7","COLUMN8"
"11/24/2013","50.67","51.22","50.67","51.12","17","0","FILE1"
"11/25/2013","51.34","51.91","51.09","51.87","23","0","FILE1"
"12/30/2013","51.76","51.82","50.86","51.15","13","0","FILE1"
"12/31/2013","51.15","51.33","50.45","50.76","18","0","FILE1"
```

On the other hand, if the file is so large that your system chokes on `Import-CSV`, read the file with `IO.StreamReader()` and process the file row-by-row.

*Edit:*

Oh well, thousands of output files are a bit more tricky to handle. Disk I/O with lots of `Add-Content` is a performance killer, but for a single-shot operation something like this ought to work:

```
$src = "c:\temp\reallybig.csv"  # Source file
$dst = "c:\temp\file{0}.csv"    # Output file(s)
$reader = new-object IO.StreamReader($src)  # Reader for input

while(($line = $reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null){ # Loop the input
    $match = [regex]::match($line, "(?i)file(\d)") # Look for row that ends with file-and-number

    if($match.Success){
     # Add the line to respective output file. SLOW! 
     add-content $($dst -f $match.Groups[0].value) $line 
    }
}
$reader.Close() # Close the input file
```

For increased performance, output-file based `StringBuilder` buffering works quite nicely.

*Edit2:*

Here's another a version. It contains a hash table that contains StringBuilder objects. Each output file name from the last column is used as key and its value is a StringBuilder that contains text data. This approach stores all the output file data in memory, so x64 and some gigabytes of RAM is expedted for reasonably large input files. The buffers could be flushed to disk every now and then to conserver memory; this requires additional bookkeeping.

```
$src = "c:\temp\reallybig.csv"   # Source file
$dst = "c:\temp\file_{0}.csv"    # Output file(s)
$reader = new-object IO.StreamReader($src)  # Reader for input

$header = Get-Content -Path $src | select -First 1 # Get the header row

$ht = @{}
$line = $reader.ReadLine() # Skip the first line, it's alread in $header

while(($line = $reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null){ # Loop the input
    $match = [regex]::match($line, '(?i)(\w+\d)$') # Look for row that ends with file-and-number

    if($match.Success){

      $outFileName = $match.Groups[0].value # What filename output is sent to?

      if(-not $ht.ContainsKey($outFileName)) { # Output file is not yet in hashtable
        $ht.Add($outFileName, (new-object Text.StringBuilder) )
        [void]$ht[$outFileName].Append($header)
        [void]$ht[$outFileName].Append([Environment]::NewLine)
      } else { # Append data to existing file
        [void]$ht[$outFileName].Append($line)
        [void]$ht[$outFileName].Append([Environment]::NewLine)
      }
    }
}
$reader.Close() # Close the input file

# Dump the hashtable contents to individual files
$ht.GetEnumerator() | % { 
    set-content $($dst -f $_.Name) ($_.Value).ToString() 
}
```

Comment: In fact it has more than 250 000 lines.And the output should have more than 1000 small files. So I'm looking for a way how to generate more than 1000 small files automaticly. The file name for all small files is always stored in column #8.

Comment: @John Please include such a information in the original post in the future, so reasonable solutions are easier to propose.

Comment: Thank you very much it works quite good. There are some things I would like to modify somehow #1. In fact (FILE1,FIILE2...FILEN) I used only as a example (probably bad example). There can by ANY text string(A,ABC,E,EEEE,S,STAA ...) in column 8. Actually the big file is sorted alphabetically by column 8. #2. Each small file should include first line(header) of a big file. #3 Name of output files should be "TEXT STRING IN COLUMN8"+TXT"    Yes, you are right I'll try to formulate my problem better in a future. Sorry about that.

Comment: @John Try and change the regexp like so `'(?i)(\w+\d)$'` and tick the accept answer mark if you are happy.

Comment: Sorry after change it still doesn't work the way it should. Each small file should include first line(header) of a big file. There can by ANY text string(A,ABC,E,EEEE,S,STAA ...) in column #8 (but the whole big file is sorted alphabetically by column#8) Name of output files should be "TEXT STRING IN COLUMN#8".TXT Please see code below it works exactly the way it should work, only problem is that the code is quite slow(80+ minutes). It looks like your code would be much faster if it would work correctly.