# Get-ADuser and export to multiple CSV files

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm using the following command to grab users from an OU and export to csv file:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=Contoso Users,OU=Contoso,DC=domain,DC=local' -Properties * | Select UserPrincipalName, EmailAddress | Sort UserPrincipalName | Export-CSV $UsersToMigrate -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

Is there anyway to export to multiple csv files of 10 users per file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split one big text file into multiple files in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25396798/how-to-split-one-big-text-file-into-multiple-files-in-powershell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append to the respective output file in a loop and use a counter and integer division to determine the actual filename.

```
$i = 0
... | Sort UserPrincipalName | ForEach-Object {
    $csv = "C:\path\to\output_$([Math]::Floor([int]$i/[int]10)).csv"
    $_ | Export-Csv $csv -NoType -Append
    $i++
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$Users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=Contoso Users,OU=Contoso,DC=domain,DC=local' -Properties * | Select UserPrincipalName, EmailAddress | Sort UserPrincipalName
$Users | ForEach-Object -Begin {$i = 1} {
     $_ | Export-CSV "$UsersToMigrate-$([Math]::Ceiling($i++ / 10)).csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append
}
```

**Explanation**

- Iterates through the collection of users with `ForEach-Object`, initialising a counter variable `$i` as 1 in a `Begin` block first.
- Divides the counter by 10 and rounds up to the nearest integer. Uses this as part of the CSV name and exports to the CSV with the `-Append` switch (requires PSv3+ I believe).

Comment: Wow this is great. Both solutions work a treat. Thank you both so much. Great to see alternative ways of getting the same result. Thanks for the Explanation Mark, very useful. I marked Ansgar's solution as the answer as simply was the first one which worked.